# Es posible tener multiples metodos de busqueda en un mismo controladr WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Por ejemplo, Un método que busque de acuerdo a lo recibido en el parámetro "horario" del método:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(HORARIODOCENTE))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetHorariosDocente([FromUri] HORARIODOCENTE horario)
        {
            try
            {
                List<HORARIODOCENTE> lstHorariosDocente = LGHorarioDocente.GetHorarioDocente();
                List<HORARIODOCENTE> HorariosDocente = lstHorariosDocente.FindAll(x => x.IdCicloEscolar == horario.IdCicloEscolar && x.IdDocente == horario.IdDocente && x.Dia == horario.Dia && x.HoraInicio == horario.HoraInicio);

                if (HorariosDocente == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return Ok(HorariosDocente);
            }
            catch
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }
        }
```

y otro con parámetro "docente"

```
[ResponseType(typeof(HORARIODOCENTE))]
            public IHttpActionResult GetDocenteId([FromUri] HORARIODOCENTE docente)
            {
                try
                {
                    List<HORARIODOCENTE> lstHorariosDocente = LGHorarioDocente.GetHorarioDocente();
                    List<HORARIODOCENTE> Docente= lstHorariosDocente.FindAll(x => x.IdCicloEscolar == docente.IdCicloEscolar && x.IdDocente == docente.IdDocente);

                    if (Docente== null)
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    return Ok(HorariosDocente);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return InternalServerError();
                }
            }
```

Comment: ¿Si pones esos dos métodos en un mismo `Controller` te genera algún error? Por lo que veo no debería existir ningún problema ya que los métodos tienen diferente nombre.

Comment: Bueno, trato de acceder al controlador con AJAX pero como hay dos métodos si me marca error en la consola del navegador...

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7005/api/validahorainicio/?Horario%5BIdCicloEscolar%5D=6&Horario%5BIdDocente%5D=3&Horario%5BDia%5D=&Horario%5BHoraInicio%5D=i7am. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49172' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decora los *endpoints* de tu controlador con el atributo **Route**, al igual que el controlador con el atributo **RoutePrefix**:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/ValidaHoraInicio")] // Prefijo para llamar al controlador
public class ValidarHoraInicioController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet] // Indica el verbo HTTP utilizado por el endpoint
    [Route("GetHorariosDocente")] // Indica el nombre de la acción
    [ResponseType(typeof(HORARIODOCENTE))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetHorariosDocente([FromUri] HORARIODOCENTE horario)
    {
        try
        {
            // Código omitido por brevedad...
        }
        catch
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetDocenteId")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(HORARIODOCENTE))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetDocenteId([FromUri] HORARIODOCENTE docente)
    {
        try
        {
            // Código omitido por brevedad...
        }
        catch
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
}
```

Con ésto, las URI para tus solicitudes AJAX quedarían de esta forma:

- [dominio]:[puerto]/api/ValidaHoraInicio/GetHorariosDocente
- [dominio]:[puerto]/api/ValidaHoraInicio/GetDocenteId

y así puedes realizar distintos métodos de búsqueda en el mismo controlador.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es de los métodos en tu `Controller`, corresponde básicamente a un [error de Google Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743)

Lo puedes solucionar agregando en tu archivo de **hosts**. Si utilizas Windows lo puedes encontrar en **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**. La línea a agregar es:

`127.0.0.1   localhost yourdomain.com`

Para mayor información puedes consultar la siguiente [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err) de SO en inglés